# Property Changed not firing in custom renderer when caching strategy is RecycleElement in view Cell renderer

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

Hi im using xamarin forms shared. i wanna have a custom renderer for my ViewCell in list view and in OnCellPropertyChanged method do something . but when i set the CachingStrategy to RecycleElement this wont work. but before the CachingStrategy it was working perfectly.
what should i do?

Comment: I got the same problem. you found any solution?

Comment: @user3490506 im afraid not